# What's slowing ubuntu loading?

Tags: 12.04, boot

I've read enough similar topics but I think I need more guidance. I run 12.04 on a Dell desktop with i3 sandy bridge cpu and 4Gb ram which came with 11.something version. (just pointing that is a fully linux compatible system) I've installed several packages in the past of which most I don't remember anymore. Thing is that recently system has become more and more slow and I can't find out why. I check logs and startup messages but those are all arcane to me. 
I use this system as a web/print server and fax receiving/editing. I have uninstalled wine and vmware player but still nothing changed. besides some programming/server packages, openoffice and teamviewer I haven't install much.
Is there a procedure I can follow to track down what is slowing my computer?

Answer (score 0):

To see all the services that automatically starts, you can use

> initctl list shell

It will list the contents of

> /etc/init

Then check which services you don't need.

Comment: I have suspicions that something is halting system during boot. Is there a similar way to check that too?

Comment: Also, i did run the above command and I see all the services. How am i supposed to know what tty1 or procps or ufw is? There are too many services to google each one of them. Names are way too cryptic to understand.

Comment: Try to run 'top' in your shell you will see which service(s) is using your cpu.